# Request to merge tags: mumble and mumble-server

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, merge

These tags should be merged: [mumble-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mumble-server) and [mumble](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mumble)

Comment: Which one do you think should be kept? It's 50/50 on volume :p

Comment: mumble I think is the broadest one :p

Comment: @Lucas: Since I can't mail you: Please enhance your recent tag-wiki spree with the necessary attributions to Wikipedia where applicable. They have a CC-Attribution license which requires this.

Comment: woops will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completed [mulmble-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mulmble-server) has been mad a synonym of [mumble](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mumble).